# How $geoNear chooses the field of the model to find the coordenates in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, coordinates, distance

I'm using mongoose and I'm trying to get activities from the schema 'Activity' with an specific filter using $geoNear, but it always returns an empty array and I think it's because the aggregate function is not finding the coordenates of my model.

This is an example of the JSON to send:

```
{
  "coordinates": {
    "lat": 37.3890924,
    "lon": -5.984458899999936
  },
  "distance": 100000000
}
```

This is the query:

```
Activity.aggregate([
            { $geoNear: {
                near: {
                    type: "Point",
                    coordinates: [req.body.coordinates.lon, req.body.coordinates.lat]
                },
                maxDistance: req.body.distance * 1000,
                spherical: true,
                distanceField: "distance"                    
                }
            }
        ])
```

And this is the schema, where the coordinates are into the field 'meetingPoint':

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ActivitySchema = Schema({
    title: {type: String, require: true },    
    meetingPoint: {
        meet_name:{type: String, require: true }, 
        coordinates: {
            lat: {type: Number, require: true },
            lon: {type: Number, require: true }
        }
    },
    date: {type: Date, require: true },
    car: Boolean,
    sites: {type: Number, min: 0 },
    price: {type: Number, min: 0.0, require: true },
    description: String,
    eventTime: String,
    event: Boolean,
    sport: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Sport', require: true },
    owner: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', require: true },
    attenders: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
    comments: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment'}],
    ratings: [{
        rating:{type: Number},
        user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User'}
    }],
    creationDate: {type: Date, default: Date.now, require: true },
    updateDate: {type: Date, default: Date.now, require: true },
    public: Boolean,
    image: String  
});

ActivitySchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
ActivitySchema.index({location: "2dsphere"});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Activity', ActivitySchema);
```

EDIT: I changed the coordinates in mongoose schema to the GeoJSON format(I think) and now they look like this:

```
meetingPoint: {
        meet_name:{type: String, require: true }, 
        coordinates: {
            type: String,
            coordinates: []
        }
    }
```

But the result is the same.

EDIT2: I also updated the existing data in the collection according to the meetingPoint with the pertinent format. This is an example:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5ac36a2aasdsd3242b"),
"meetingPoint" : { "meet_name" : "Av. de Menéndez Pelayo, 76, 41030 Madrid, España", "coordinates" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ -5.984458899
9936, 37.3890924 ] } },
"attenders" :....
```

But I still receive no activities with the filter.

Comment: The data is invalid. MongoDB only recognizes ["legacy coordinate pairs"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/#legacy-coordinate-pairs) where named keys are in the "specific order" of. **longitude** then **latitude**. So your ` the data on location is not added to the index since it does not match the format. I suggest you update your stored format to [GeoJSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/#geospatial-geojson) for the best compatibility. No geospatial index queries will be able to work with the present data format.

Comment: @NeilLunn I edited the post showing what I understood by what you said. The result is the same though.

Comment: You didn't understand. It's not the "schema", it is the actual stored data. Changing the mongoose schema does not change what's already in the collection unless you reloaded all the data from scratch. You need to "update" the "exsising **data** in the collection".

Comment: @NeilLunn I already updated the stored data in the collection in the correct way I think, but I still don't get any result with the filter. Do you have any other idea why it could be happening?